# When does $E[max(X_1, ..., X_n)]$ = $\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i]$ hold true?

Tags: probability-theory

Consider **independent** random variables $X_1, ..., X_n \ge 0$ with $E[X_i] > 0 $.

In which cases does $E[max(X_1, ..., X_n)]$ = $\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i]$ hold true?

For two Variables I found $X_1 = 1$ and $X_2 = 0$ with probability $1-\epsilon$ and $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ otherwise when $\epsilon$ approaches $0$.

Is there an example for more than two variables?

Comment: Take all $X_i=0$ to obtain an example for all $n$.

Comment: As stated the expected value of all variables are larger than $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\max (X_1,X_2,...,X_n)\leq X_1+X_2+..+X_n$. If the given condition holds then both sides have the same expectation. This is true iff $\max (X_1,X_2,...,X_n)= X_1+X_2+..+X_n$ with probability $1$  which mean all but one $X_i$ is $0$ with  probability $1$. Can you now use independence to show  that there exist $i$ such that $P(X_j=0 \forall j \neq i)=1$? [Look at $EX_iX_j=EX_iEX_j$].

Comment: I agree that for almost all $\omega \in \Omega$ there is an $i$ such that $X_j(\omega)=0$ for $j\neq i$, but i do not agree that there there is an $i$ such that $P(X_j = 0 \forall j\neq i)=1$. Take for instance $X_i = 1_{A_i}$ where $A_1,A_2,\dots A_n$ is a partition of $\Omega$.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen For that part independence is crucial. You don't have independence in your example.

Comment: Ahh. Of course. My bad.